# Odd printing behavior in C

Tags: c, integer, printf

I'm trying to print out comma seperated values in my C program, but I think I keep getting memory allocations instead.
When running from the command line, this happens.

```
1
  49 this is the response
  10 this is the response
1
  49 this is the response
  10 this is the response
```

Here is my program:

```
void main(){
    int j;
    int idnum;
    j = 0;
    char entry[99];
    do{
        idnum = get_field(entry);
        j++;
    }
    while(idnum!='\n' && idnum!= ',' && j!= MAXTYPES);
    int recur = 0;
    while (recur != 4){
        printf("%4d\n", entry[recur]);
        recur++;
    }
    printf("\nEnd of Input\n");
}

int get_field(char entry[]){
    int idnum;
    char n;
    int j = 0;
    char temp[45];
    while ((n=getchar())!= EOF){
        printf("%d this is the response\n",n);

    }
    return idnum;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want `printf("%c this is the response\n",n);` ?

Answer (score 1):

Problems I see:

1. In `get_field`, you have not initialized `idnum` and returning it from the function.
2. In `get_field`, the `while` loop to read the data is strange. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish. However, you if type `1` and then press `Enter`, two characters are added to the input stream: `'1'` and `'\n'`. You are reading them as char, using `getchar`, and printing them as `int` (by using the `"%d"` format).

   That explains the output you are getting.

   49 is the decimal representation of `'1'`.

   10 is the decimal representation of `'\n'`
3. The return type of `getchar` is `int`. You should change the type of `n` in `get_field` to `int` from `char`. That could be source of problems depending on the platform you are working in.

Answer (score 0):

With `%d` you are printing the ASCII values. ASCII value of 1 is 49 and of `\n` is 10. 
These are what you are getting.

You may want to print them with `%c`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `n` is a `char` type data.So,you've to use `%c` instead of `%d` Like this:

```
    printf("%c this is the response\n",n);
```